# Does using ioc really help for a Xamarin Forms application with 5 tabbed screens?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

The main page of my application looks like this:

```
public partial class MainPage : TabbedPage
{

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var homePage = new NavigationPage(new HomePage())
        {
            Title = "Home",
            Icon = "ionicons_2_0_1_home_outline_25.png"
        };
        var helpPage = new NavigationPage(new HelpPage())
        {
            Title = "Help",
            Icon = "ionicons_2_0_1_help_outline_25.png"
        };
        var settingsPage = new NavigationPage(new SettingsPage())
        {
            Title = "Settings",
            Icon = "ionicons_2_0_1_settings_25.png"
        };
        var cardsPage = new NavigationPage(new Cards())
        {
            Title = "Cards",
            Icon = "ionicons_2_0_1_photos_outline_25.png"
        };

        App.phrasesFrame = new NavigationPage(new PhrasesFrame())
        {
            Title = "Play",
            Icon = "ionicons_2_0_1_play_outline_25.png",
            BarTextColor = Color.White
        };

        Children.Add(homePage);
        Children.Add(helpPage);
        Children.Add(settingsPage);
        Children.Add(cardsPage);
        Children.Add(App.phrasesFrame);

    }

}
```

It's been suggested I use ioc for the application but before letting someone change this for me I would like to get some advice on if there are really any any advantages in using ioc just for creation and usage of these pages.

The reason I am asking is that in the past I have been involved with projects that added ioc and then become so complex with all the view models that the devs wished they had just left the working projects alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there are no performance advantages. Inversion of Control (IOC) and Dependency Injection (DI) are common patterns in software development.

If you are planning to implement Unit testing and UI Testing and having a readable code I highly recommend using IOS or DI.

Software patterns take longer to implement but its worth it on the long run / passing your project to someone else.

You can learn how to implement it [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2017/10/03/dependency-injection-xamarin/)

**My Opinion / Me ranting :**

I personally make it a requirement to have a software pattern , It makes me write better quality code and makes it easy for growing projects. It also reduces code debt which can prevent weird errors from happening. Its depressing reading badly written code